# python psutil on windows gives access denied

Tags: python, windows

os: windows professional

i am trying to use psutil to get a list of processes and their cpu usage, i ran the script as administrator and it fails when it encounters process DymoPnpService.exe, what could be the issue?

```
import psutil

def process():
    plist = psutil.get_process_list()
    plist = sorted(plist, key=lambda i: i.name)
    for i in plist:
        print i.name, i.get_cpu_percent()

def main():
    process()


main()
```

AcroRd32.exe 0.0
    AcroRd32.exe 0.0
    DymoPnpService.exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krisdigitx\Documents\windowsutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\krisdigitx\Documents\windowsutil.py", line 10, in main
    process()
  File "C:\Users\krisdigitx\Documents\windowsutil.py", line 7, in process
    print i.name, i.get_cpu_percent()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 330, in get_cpu_percent
    pt1 = self._platform_impl.get_cpu_times()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\_psmswindows.py", line 125, in wrapper
    raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._process_name)
AccessDenied: (pid=1832, name='DymoPnpService.exe')
```

**more research:**

strange i can run the program from the windows command prompt...but it fails in the python ide

Comment: What does this have to do with Debian?

Comment: My guess is that it is executed as SYSTEM

Comment: "strange i can run the program from the windows command prompt...but it fails in the python ide" - I bet the IDE runs the script in an interpreter sub-process that does not have Admin privileges even if you run the IDE as Administrator.  But when you run it from the command line, your specifically running the interpreter as Administrator (assuming your user is an Admin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run this in a cmd.exe prompt: `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq DymoPnpService.exe" /V` and check the "User Name".  If it is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" then it is probably intentionally not allowing even an Administrator account to get cpu times, %, etc of the proc.

Grab a copy of [Process Explorer](http://www.sysinternals.com/) and find the path of the process and check the Security Tab of the Preferences right click menu option.  To fix you *may* be able to edit the Owner or Permissions of the DymoPnpService.exe executable but this could cause unexpected issues in Windows.

---

You can also just continue the loop if the process doesn't allow you to get details about it:

```
import psutil

def process():
    plist = psutil.get_process_list()
    plist = sorted(plist, key=lambda i: i.name)
    for i in plist:
        try:
            print i.name, i.get_cpu_percent()
        except AccessDenied:
            print "'%s' Process is not allowing us to view the CPU Usage!" % i.name

def main():
    process()

main()
```

Comment: the user in the security tab for the service is listed as "user <access denied>" .....

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 0.6.0 psutil on Windows will no longer raise AccessDenied for different process methods (cpu_percent() amongst them):
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/psutil/oxAd0BuAzt0%5B1-25%5D

Comment: Just to bring that up to date: current version of psutil is 5.7.2. The mentioned Google Group is not available any more and I encounter the same error message when trying to access the `threads()` function of some processes.