# Python's psutil module and a bizarre issue

Tags: python, windows, process, psutil

This works perfectly:

```
def find_processes():
    name = "ProcessName.exe"
    pid_list = psutil.get_pid_list()
    for pid in pid_list:
        try:
            if str(psutil.Process(pid).name()) == name:
                return True
        except:
            pass
    return False
```

This doesn't:

```
def find_processes():
    name = "ProcessName.exe"
    pid_list = psutil.get_pid_list()
    for pid in pid_list:
        if str(psutil.Process(pid).name()) == name:
            return True
    return False
```

It raises an error: AccessDenied: (pid=560)
I'm on a Windows environment and need to access all the processes' names. I already have a working code (the former), so my question is more out of curiosity.

What do the `try`/`except` statements do in the first example, and why is it not working if I remove them in the second?

Comment: What's the difference? (Besides the indentation.)

Comment: You don't appear to have removed the try except statements in the second case.

Comment: @ebarr silly me didn't edit properly. Now there should be a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the information from each process will be available to you unless you are the root user/administrator. See this question: [python psutil on windows gives access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349854/python-psutil-on-windows-gives-access-denied).

You would be better off changing your first example to specifically catch these cases, with:

```
try:    
    if str(psutil.Process(pid).name()) == name:      
        return True    
except AccessDenied:    
    print "Unable to access PID:",pid
```

Comment: So what happens is that in the first example some processes won't be available and will throw an error, but because I catched it with an except statement the loop continues, whereas without the try/except combination the loop exits at the first error it encounters?

Comment: @DanielShaw Yup, exactly that. The reason that I added `except AccessDenied` rather than just `except` is that I only want the loop to ignore `AccessDenied` type errors. All other errors should be raised normally, causing the code to exit.