# Is it possible to find the location of a file with the help of its PID?

Tags: python, location, exe, pid

I have some PID (process I'D) and i have to find the location of the files to which these PIDs belong. I have to write a code in python language. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `psutil`?
install `psutil`:

```
pip install psutil
```

`psutil` has an exe method which will return an absolute path to the ruunning process:

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.exe()
```

and the output will be something like this:

```
'/usr/libexec/xartstorageremoted'
```

Comment: this link might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350792/8783668

Comment: Tried this too.